# Очередь на выполнение потоков C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl, очередь-задач

Как я могу создать очередь потоков, что бы они выполнялись в каком-то пуле по 50 штук, например ? То есть одновременно выполнялось 50 каких-то тасков и как только один из них закончился, из очереди брался следующий и так пока вся очередь не закончится.

Comment: можно создать наследника класса TaskScheduler и в нем управлять Thread'ами для выполнения Task'ов.

Comment: пример реализации наследника TaskScheduler см. [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs,30) -- используется по-умолчанию при работе с Task'ами.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но **именно так** и устроен стандартный thread pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобный функционал можно реализовать при помощи [семафоров](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/11.8.php).

Создаёте семафор, который может одновременно использовать необходимое количество потоков. Если потоков больше, то "лишние" потоки не будут выполняться до тех пор пока в семафоре не освободится хотя бы одно место.

Comment: У меня очередь на 30 тысяч задач и из-за этого кидает Out of memory эксепшен. Как в таком случае быть ?

Comment: Если в двух словах, то выполнить оптимизацию. Но, как это сделать, тема заслуживающая отдельного разговора. Вероятнее всего изначальный вопрос и семафоры сами по себе здесь вообще не при чём. ИМХО, в данном случае, лучше всего задать отдельный вопрос с подробным описанием как Вы создаёте эту очередь и как Вы с ней работаете. Тогда, Вам смогут как-то здесь помочь.

Comment: @Neustart: об этом действительно лучше задать отдельный вопрос. В нём расскажите не только что вы делаете, но — прежде всего — какую задачу таким способом решаете. Возможно, вам предложат более оптимальные пути решения.